# What is pam_unix2 / why doesn't it exist on some distributions?

Tags: pam

Some documentations, blogs and forums and other examples on the web use `pam_unix2` in `/etc/pam.d/` configurations. An example taken from [pam_winbind](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/pam_winbind.8.html)  manpage:

```
auth      required        pam_env.so
auth      sufficient      pam_unix2.so
auth      required        pam_winbind.so  use_first_pass
account   requisite       pam_unix2.so
account   required        pam_winbind.so  use_first_pass
password  sufficient      pam_winbind.so
password  requisite       pam_pwcheck.so  cracklib
password  required        pam_unix2.so    use_authtok
session   required        pam_unix2.so
session   required        pam_winbind.so
```

It seems pam_unix2 was merely meant to: *additionally support bcrypt Blowfish-based password hashing* (Debian [RFP #237856](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=237856)).

The manpages are: [pam_unix](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pam_unix.8.html) and [pam_unix2](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pam_unix2.8.html)

What is the difference between `pam_unix.so` and `pam_unix2.so` ? Which are still used? maintained? relevant ?

Answer (score 4):

The package was originaly created by Thorsten Kukuk from SuSE. The  original upstream FTP repository has disappeared (according to [debian watch file](https://sources.debian.net/src/libpam-unix2/1:2.6-2/debian/copyright/) it was `ftp.suse.com/people/kukuk/pam/pam_unix2/`...  [some mirrors](http://ftp.isr.ist.utl.pt/pub/MIRRORS/ftp.suse.com/people/kukuk/pam/pam_unix2/) still exist)

It seems that SuSE used and maintained that fork for a while, but it seems that Red Hat/CentOS/Scientific Linux never provided it [RFE #173002](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=173002). Also, Debian/Ubuntu provided it as an extra package, but it was removed from Jessie because it's buggy and unmaintained ([Grave bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729813) => [autoremoval](https://packages.qa.debian.org/libp/libpam-unix2/news/20131217T163910Z.html) => [supported debian dists with pam_unix2](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libpam-unix2))

OpenSUSE still provides pam_unix2 (2.9.1) in their [pam-modules](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/Linux-PAM/pam-modules) package.
In OpenSuSE Factory, pam-modules Version: 12.1 Release: 73.9, it says
*"**This package contains additional, obsolete PAM Modules sometimes
needed for migration**: pam_unix2 and pam_pwcheck"* ([link](https://build.opensuse.org/package/binary/Linux-PAM/pam-modules?arch=x86_64&filename=pam-modules-12.1-73.9.x86_64.rpm&repository=openSUSE_Factory))

Nowadays, pam_unix supports blowfish.

pam_unix2 seems unmaintained (opensuse use pam_unix2 version 2.9.1, which is 3 years old).

**Finally, pam_unix2 lacks many pam_unix options.**