# CentOS 7: enabling blowfish hashes for password authentication

Tags: centos, password, glibc

In our organization, we are distributing pre-hashed password values for a number of local accounts. Currently, these accounts' passwords are hashed using Blowfish (`$2a$[...]`) or Blowfish-8-bit (`$2y$[...]`). Other distros we are using are capable of handling this, but RedHat / CentOS seems to [deliberately be lacking support for Blowfish in glibc](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=173834) as it is.

Is there any way to make CentOS/RedHat systems handle Blowfish hashes without profoundly breaking its serviceability through the standard update channels?

I am deploying CentOS 7.2 with a simplistic kickstart configuration and a minimal package selection:

```
%packages --nobase --ignoremissing
@core
kexec-tools

%end
```

Comment: It would seem what you want implies a modified glibc, passwd and other essential packages, which is IMHO not what you want.

Comment: Theoretically, it might be conceivable to roll your own PAM module which mimics the usual one but statically adds support for Blowfish, but I'd not go down that path.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz this sounds like an idea. But I refrained from rolling an own module and stole one instead. Thanks!

Comment: @syneticon-dj: why don't you move that into an answer, I'll gladly upvote it. (When we were in a similar situation, we ended up saying "**** it" and now have one SuSE login node and otherwise all CentOS backends.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz done. Thanks for the hint, It certainly has saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Ulrich Schwarz mentioned a custom PAM module in the comments to the question, I figured I could go and see what SLES, which makes Blowfish the default, is using.

Turns out it is a separate module called `pam_unix2.so` not conflicting with anything on the CentOS system. As a proof-of-concept, I have copied `/lib64/security/pam_unix2.so` off a SLES 11 SP4 system to `/usr/lib64/security/pam_unix2.so` on the CentOS host and downloaded and installed its dependency [libxcrypt](ftp://ftp.opensuse.org/distribution/12.1/repo/oss/suse/x86_64/libxcrypt-3.0.4-11.1.2.x86_64.rpm) which again is a SuSE package, but works on CentOS 7 for this narrow purpose.

Adding

```
auth        sufficient    pam_unix2.so
```

to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` allows me to authenticate against a Blowfish-crypted password on the console.

To make sure `authconfig` will not break the configuration on the next invocation, the symlink `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` pointing to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac` should be replaced with a copy of `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac`.

Bottom line:
SuSE's *pam_unix2* module seems like the least invasive method to get Blowfish hashes accepted, although it also means that I would need to monitor security announcements for *pam_unix2* and *libxcrypt* separately.

Comment: The last version of `pam_unix2` is available in openSUSE's [`pam-modules`](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/Linux-PAM/pam-modules) package, but it's effectively abandoned; see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208213/86440) and [the author's message confirming it's dead upstream](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729813#33).

Comment: @StephenKitt  SLES 11 / OES is using it as the primary password authentication module out of the box, so security updates will be made available throughout the support cycle of SLES 11 (at least to SLES customers, but I suppose they will be corrected in OpenSUSE as well).

Comment: Yup, you still have a few years of support; I just wanted to point out that `pam_unix2` doesn't seem to have much of a long-term future. (So now is the time to start planning a transition away from `bcrypt`-hashed passwords.)